# How do I implement a collision at a point?

Tags: sprite-kit

Should I create an invisible `SKNode` for a user touch? Or can I emulate a collision at a point?

I think I got the proper collision "detection":

```
CGPoint currentPoint = [((UITouch*)(touches.allObjects.firstObject)) locationInNode:self];
if([_ball containsPoint:currentPoint])
{
    [_ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:impulseVector atPoint:currentPoint];
}
```

This however sometimes results in the "touch" and the sprite to pass through each other. I'm wondering if just creating a `SKNode` that represents the touch is the expected way to handle this, or if I can handle it by "point" of contact.

Comment: Are you looking to check if a user's touch is on a node?

Comment: No I have "that" part -- as included in the original post. I don't need to detect a collision, I'm looking to implement the collision. I think I'm going to end up adding a node that represents the touch though.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to track the user touch with an actor (SKNode) that represents the user.